# git when you push your changes to the remote are the files under .git updated?

Tags: windows, git, githooks

So I have added a hook file into the .git/hooks folder called post-checkout.

The hook is working, but when I do a git status I don't see the new file. Also if I try to add the file with `git add .git/hooks/post-checkout` it gives an error.

I assume that means that the .git folder is local information only? - but I want to share my hooks with the remote repo. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, git informations are not relative **only** to local - remote informations are tracked, stored local, but not in sync as long as you don't use `fetch` command - but git hooks are.

What you can't do is to include in your repository something that's into `.git` folder: if you want to share some hooks, create a file that's in your repo, named `post-checkout.dist` and write a README about its usage.

If you don't want to have a double copy of this file, use symlinks in `hooks` folder